# How to delete the beta application submitted to Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I need help for removing the beta app submitted in google play store, Recently I have submitted my app with Targeted SDK version 23 for beta testing but now I want to submit the app with targeted SDK version 15 for production.

I have tried by submitting the App to Production with targeted SDK version 15 but it showed me an error saying:

> Permission model downgrade PROBLEM: Users that have the APK version
>   code XXXX1, which targets SDK 23 or higher, will receive an error when
>   they attempt to upgrade to this apk XXXX2 because it targets SDK 15.

Is there any way to delete the existing beta app or to submit the production app with SDK15 other than un-publishing the app? Un-publishing the app will cause the inconvenience to existing users.

Comment: how did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issues

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to delete a build from the Alpha or Beta channels. What you have to do is, deploy an artifact with a higher build code to the channel, then promote the channel to production. The APK that you want to remove will not show up, only the build with the highest build code, so there is no risk to doing this.

(source - just worked with Google Play support on a similar issue.)

Comment: The problem is we cannot go with the SDK version 23 as we have encountered few application issues with that SDK level so we want to go with the SDK version14